# Check account status as a Samba domain member

Tags: samba, active-directory

I have a Rocky Linux 8.5 machine running as an Active Directory domain member.
I've added it to the domain with *net ads join* command and I can run several commands to list domain objects as expected. The services *smb*, *nmb* and *winbind* are all active. Samba version is 4.14.5.

I was hoping to find some way to check if an user account is enabled/disabled in the same fashion as the below on Windows:

> net user *username* /domain

In the output the "Account active" property shows its status.

How could I get that information on this Linux machine?

Thanks!